# VB.Net and XDocument - Group By

Tags: asp.net, xml, vb.net, linq-to-xml

I have the following code which I need to amend to `group by offer` but I'm not sure how to add in the `group by` part in this query.

Any ideas?

```
propertyInfo = myXmlFile.Descendants("offer").Descendants("site") _
    .Where(Function(f) _
    f.Attributes("code").First.Value = Location.Text) _
    .Select(Function(f) New With { _
    .LOCATION = f.Attributes("code").First.Value, _
    .TITLE = f.Parent.Attributes("title").First.Value, _
    .OFFER = f.Parent.Attributes("offerid").First.Value, _
    .POPUPDESC = f.Parent.Descendants("short_desc").Value
```

Example XML

```
<offers>
  <offer title="Offer title" offerid="AS32">
    <short_desc><![CDATA[
        <div>Your HTML's body <a href='dfgdfgdfgdfg.html'>Offer title</a>
        </div>
    ]]></short_desc>

    <site code="CO">
      <year_week_start>201344</year_week_start>
      <year_week_end>201414</year_week_end>
    </site>

    <site code="FH">
      <year_week_start>201446</year_week_start>
      <year_week_end>201450</year_week_end>
    </site>
  </offer>
</offers>
```

Comment: Do you really need to do it with the LINQ method syntax? I think for tasks like grouping the query syntax http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531412.aspx is easier to handle. And a sample of the XML would help. Do you want to group by the attribute `offerid`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to be a little more specific in what you want after you group. It's pretty easy to group, but then you get an enumerable of groups:

```
propertyInfo = myXmlFile.Descendants("offer").Descendants("site") _
    .Where(Function(f) _
    f.Attributes("code").First.Value = Location.Text) _
    .Select(Function(f) New With { _
    .LOCATION = f.Attributes("code").First.Value, _
    .TITLE = f.Parent.Attributes("title").First.Value, _
    .OFFER = f.Parent.Attributes("offerid").First.Value, _
    .POPUPDESC = f.Parent.Descendants("short_desc").Value) _
    .GroupBy(Function(f) f.OFFER)
```